# WPF Binding only reacts to the first value change

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

My WPF control has a DependencyPropery that forwards its value to the view model. The property is bound to a view model property (`Message.ReceptionState`) in the parent control.

Now when the source property (`ReceptionState`) updates, the binding correctly forwards the value but also detaches itself from the `Message.PropertyChanged` event in the process, so all the following changes are ignored by the UI. The binding is definitely set up as one-way but it behaves like it would in one-time mode. Only when I change the binding to two-way it behaves correctly.

I checked the .NET source code and this actually seems to be the intended behavior (see WindowsBase/System/Windows/DependencyObject.cs: 742). If the binding isn't set to two-way, WPF stores the value on the first `PropertyChanged` and then detaches from the it. But I really don't get why it would do that. How can I tell the UI to keep showing changes in the view model without changing all my dependency properties to two-way?

Here are the relevant pieces of my code, in case it helps clarify things. I'm on .NET Core 3.1 with a self-made MVVM framework.

ReceiptStateIndicator.xaml.cs:

```cs
public static readonly DependencyProperty StateProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("State", typeof(ReceptionState), typeof(ReceiptStateIndicator), new PropertyMetadata((d, v) =>
    {
        var indicator = (ReceiptStateIndicator)d;
        ((ReceiptStateIndicatorVM)indicator.root.DataContext).State = (ReceptionState)v.NewValue;
    }));

public ReceptionState State
{
    get => (ReceptionState)this.GetValue(StateProperty);
    set => this.SetValue(StateProperty, value);
}
```

ConversationMessage.cs:

```cs
private readonly LinkedList<PropertyChangedEventHandler> propertyChanged = new LinkedList<PropertyChangedEventHandler>();
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged
{
    add => propertyChanged.AddLast(value);
    remove => propertyChanged.Remove(value); //TODO: event listener is detached after one invocation here!
}

public ReceptionState ReceptionState
{
    get => receptionState;
    protected set
    {
        receptionState = value;

        foreach (var handler in propertyChanged)
            handler?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(ReceptionState)));
    }
}
```

TextChatBubble.xaml:

```xaml
<bubbles:ReceiptStateIndicator State="{Binding Message.ReceptionState, Mode=OneWay}"
                               Width="12" Height="12"
                               Margin="5 0"
                               VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                               FlowDirection="LeftToRight">
</bubbles:ReceiptStateIndicator>
```

Comment: Why would WPF detach from a one-way binding? This makes no sense at all. Please provide an example that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: Working on it. But of course in my demo example everything works correctly...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your State on changed handler.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty StateProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("State", typeof(ReceptionState), typeof(ReceiptStateIndicator), new PropertyMetadata((d, v) =>
    {
        var indicator = (ReceiptStateIndicator)d;
        ((ReceiptStateIndicatorVM)indicator.root.DataContext).State = (ReceptionState)v.NewValue;
    }));
```

You're writing directly to your view model property which is erasing the binding.

Don't do this. Let the binding do its work. Remove the on changed handler.

Comment: Then how do I update the view model when the property is changed? Should I bind the dependency property to the view model in XAML instead?

Comment: Yes. Do it in XAML.

Comment: I've experimented a little with your approach but I can't seem to get the binding right. How can I bind the ```State``` property to the view model in XAML? My VM is created like this: ```<Grid x:Name="root" DataContext="{Binding ReceiptStateIndicator, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"></Grid>```